# Can I access table.id used in SELECT in INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Please see my query below. Can I access  "numbers.id" in the INNER JOIN so I can write: (notice WHERE numberID = numbers.id)

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 numberID, cbListReason, cbListReasonVoteCount 
FROM reasons WHERE numberID = numbers.id  
GROUP BY 
    numberID, cbListReason, cbListReasonVoteCount 
ORDER BY cbListReasonVoteCount DESC) groupedReasons
```

rather then how it is below? I am not very well versed in SQL and while I have my index and can see execution plan uses it, I think selecting by numbers.id in INNER JOIN would make it faster.

Am I wrong?
Thanks

Query:

```
SELECT
    numbers.*,
    groupedReasons.cbListReason,
    groupedReasons.cbListReasonVoteCount
FROM
    numbers
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            TOP 1 numberID,
            cbListReason,
            cbListReasonVoteCount
        FROM
            reasons
        GROUP BY
            numberID,
            cbListReason,
            cbListReasonVoteCount
        ORDER BY
            cbListReasonVoteCount DESC
    ) groupedReasons ON numbers.id = groupedReasons.numberID
WHERE
    userCountry = @userCountry
    AND numbers.nationalNumber = @nationalNumber
    AND numbers.reportCount > @minimumReportCount
ORDER BY
    groupedReasons.cbListReasonVoteCount DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot reference other objects in the `JOIN` clause, only in the `ON`. This means that syntax like the below would fail:

```sql
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     JOIN (SELECT TOP (1) * FROM dbo.Table2 T2 WHERE T1.C = T2.C ORDER BY S) ON T1.I = T2.I
```

But also, the same would fail with a TVF:

```sql
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     CROSS JOIN dbo.TVF(T1.I) TVF
```

Instead you need to use `APPLY`. `CROSS APPLY` is the equivilent of an `INNER JOIN` and `OUTER APPLY` that of a `LEFT JOIN`. So for the above you might have statements like the below:

```sql
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) * FROM dbo.Table2 T2 WHERE T1.C = T2.C AND T1.I = T2.C ORDER BY S) T2
--Or
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     OUTER APPLY dbo.TVF(T1.C) TVF
```

Comment: Much appropriated. Thank you